# Facebook - feed gaming, using an Iframe

Tags: facebook, html, flash, iframe, feed

Iv'e noticed that if you share a sound cloud track to the new Facebook feed, onece you click the play button, the player is embedded inside of an iframe and not a flash movie.

Is that a new feature, or is that custom made for SoundCloud?

I cannot see it mentioned in the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/feed-gaming

Comment: It is custom made for SoundCloud.

Comment: @bodi0, can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: I have also with ReverbNation's wall posts. I doubt Facebook develops anything for anyone, but instead has poorly documented / hidden parts of their Graph API that were used by the in house devs. Here's to finding the solution.